# Tem como uma imagem ocupar a tela inteira existindo um mat-card em angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Estou fazendo um projeto em angular, estou ainda no início do framework então não entendo muito sobre, gostaria de saber se consigo colocar uma imagem de fundo do projeto, tendo em mente que o título e subtítulo ficaram a cima da imagem.[Tela principal do projeto que quero colocar ela preenchendo toda grade que ela é proposta a fazer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCzbU.png)